# Why my Linqued query is not giving me proper result?

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have this sql query which gives me proper result i.e all the names of employee sorted by A to Z using order by clause

```
select Distinct(EmpNTLogin),Employee from Attendance 
where  CreateDate>='2016-01-01'
order by EmpNTLogin
```

when I converted the same query in Linq,I am getting the right result but order  by clause is not working.
here is my Linqued Query

```
    var query = (from attendance in db.Attendances
                     orderby attendance.EmpNTLogin
                     where attendance.CreateDate.Value.Year >= 2016
                     select new { attendance.Employee, attendance.EmpNTLogin }).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the linq query, the distinct is applied after the `orderby` and therefore the order is discarded.

Apply the orderby after the call to distinct

```
var query = (from attendance in db.Attendances
             where attendance.CreateDate.Value.Year >= 2016
             select new
             {
                 attendance.Employee,
                 attendance.EmpNTLogin
             }).Distinct().OrderBy(att => att.EmpNTLogin);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first apply the 'where' clause and then apply the 'orderby' clause.
Something like this :

```
var query = (from attendance in db.Attendances
                 where attendance.CreateDate.Value.Year >= 2016
                 orderby attendance.EmpNTLogin
                 select new { attendance.Employee, attendance.EmpNTLogin }).Distinct();
```

Comment: still not getting :(